# How to Draw Lines with delay?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

How to add a time delay while drawing line in picturebox? I am using C #,visual studio 2010.

```
Graphics g = picturebox.CreateGraphics();
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
{
  //Draw  Line 1
  g.DrawLine(p,j*3,j*3,100,100);

  //----->How to put a Delay for 2 seconds So I
  //      see the first line then see the second after 2 sec

  //Draw  Line 2
  g.DrawLine(p,j*10,j*10,100,100);
}
```

Comment: You'll need a *very* different way to program Winforms when this gets to be a goal.  Winforms supports it well, but the standard project template doesn't help you get there.  Google "winforms game loop" to find hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a timer on your drawing form. When you're ready to draw, enable the timer and start keeping track of the various lines that you need to draw (for example, in a list / array). Every time the timer fires draw 1 line in the timer's callback function and increment your "line index" (which line to draw next). When all lines are drawn, disable the timer.

For example:

```
public partial class DrawingForm : Form
{
    Timer m_oTimer = new Timer ();

    public DrawingForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        m_oTimer.Tick += new EventHandler ( m_oTimer_Tick );
        m_oTimer.Interval = 2000;
        m_oTimer.Enabled = false;
    }

    // Enable the timer and call m_oTimer.Start () when
    // you're ready to draw your lines.

    void m_oTimer_Tick ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // Draw the next line here; disable
        // the timer when done with drawing.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple Timer (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) and keep track of the current line index.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private int index;

    private void frmBrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        index = 0;
        timer.Interval = 2000;
        timer.Start();
    }   

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         index++;
         pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
         Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
         for (int j = 1; j < index; j++) {
             g.DrawLine(p,j*3,j*3,100,100);
             g.DrawLine(p,j*10,j*10,100,100);
         }
    }
}
```

Wrote this from head, it's not tested.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions in the other answers that add a pause by using a timer are correct but if you want the drawing of a single line to be shown slowly as well you'll need to do more that that.

You could write your own line drawing method and split the drawing of the line into segments and pause between the segments.

A quick alternative is using WPF instead of WinForms:

- Add the line to a Canvas with its start and endpoint at the same position.
- Add an animation to the endpoint that will move it to the desired location
- Upon completion, do the same thing for the next line.

This way you do not have to write the line drawing code nor the timers.

Answer (score -3):

using System.Threading;

Thread.sleep(2000);

Comment: This will block the UI thread - your app will appear to hang.