# Edit properties of Graphics object c#

Tags: c#, graphics, thread-sleep

I'm currently trying to implement alternating colors using Threads for a Graphics object on a Windows Form in C#.

The code to draw a line works as follows:

```
 public void DrawLine(int toX,int toY) //draw line
    {
        g.DrawLine(currPen, xPos, yPos, toX, toY);
        xPos = toX;
        yPos = toY;
    }
```

The variables assigned at the top of the Canvass class are as follows:

```
    Graphics g;
    public static Pen Red, Blue, Green, redGreen;
    public static int xPos, yPos;
    public static Pen currPen;
    public static Thread newThread;
    public static bool flag = false;
    public static bool running = false;
```

The method of thread so far changes the color of the box which will be used to turn on flashing colors (This method is currently inside another class and will interact with static void's inside the Canvass class):

```
private void pictureBox6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        running = !running;
    }

    public void redgreenMethod()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (running != true) continue;
            if (flag == false)
            {
                flag = true;
                pictureBox6.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox6.BackColor = Color.Green;
                flag = false;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);

        }

    }
```

My issue is, I'm not too sure how to implement the threading onto a line on the Graphics canvass.. As seen in the Threads method, it interacts with the background colour of a pictureBox, whereas this kind of property isn't available for a line being drawn.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

What your looking for is the Timer object
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

add it to your win forms using the toolbox enable it in the properties and add the event by double clicking on it

```cs
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    running = !running;

    if (running)
        iter = 0
    else
        iter = -1
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (iter)
    {
        case 0:
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            iter++;
            break;
        case 1:
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            iter = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

don't forget to add your iterator int to your class

```cs
private int iter = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Sadly, I think you may have miss understood my question a little bit. As seen in your response: "pictureBox1.BackColor" is being accessed, however, this isn't what I'm trying to change. Once a line has been drawn via the graphics: "g.DrawLine", the properties of this line are then inaccessible. I need to find out how to actually access these properties so I can use them inside the Thread method.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawline i think your problem might be that your missing "PaintEventArgs" im not sure what properties are getting inaccessible.

Comment: So when a line is drawn on the canvass.. I want to change the colour of the line that has been drawn but I cannot access the lines properties as there’s no object reference for it as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

GDI+ (that's the library you are using when drawing in a WinForms application) does not store the things you are drawing as objects but only sets pixel colors.

You must create your own object model to have access to these objects. Example

```cs
public abstract class Shape
{
    public Pen Pen { get; set;}

    public abstract void Draw(Graphics g);
}

public class Line : Shape
{
    public Point From { get; set; }
    public Point To { get; set; }

    public override void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawLine(Pen, From, To);
    }
}

... other shapes
```

Then you would create a list of shapes

```cs
private readonly List<Shape> Shapes = new();
```

and in the Paint event handler you draw the graphic

```cs
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    foreach (Shape shape in Shapes) {
        shape.Draw(g);
    }
}
```

Now, instead of directly drawing things you would add new shapes to the list of shapes and invalidate the picture box to have it redrawn

```cs
public void DrawLine(int toX,int toY) //draw line
{
    Shapes.Add(
        new Line {
            Pen = currPen,
            From = new Point(xPos, yPos),
            To = new Point(toX, toY)
        }
    );
    xPos = toX;
    yPos = toY;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

You can user a [Timer object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to time and trigger your animation. Note that the `Timer.Tick` event is raised in the UI thread, so that you will not run into multithreading issues.

See also this answer to the [How to Draw Lines with delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17101720/880990) question.

It is important not to draw directly and to delegate this work to the Paint event handler, because this paint event might also be triggered, e.g., when another window on top of your application is closed. On the other hand, e.g., when your application is iconized, this event will not be triggered.

You can also [reduce flicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#to-reduce-flicker) by setting `pictureBox1.DoubleBuffered = true;`.

Comment: Awesome response! Slight problem however, when creating the list, under the "new()" part, it says it isn't supported by the version of  C#. After some research, I could see that it needs to be run on C# 9.0 and mine is currently 7.3. I've installed Visual Studio 2022 and installed .Net5 but it won't allow Windows Form Apps to run on .NET 5!

Comment: Simply use the long form `private readonly List<Shape> Shapes = new List<Shape>();`. You can also add [<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) to a group in your .csproj file to use C# 10.0. This feature ([target typed new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new)) does not depend on the framework version used. Only on the language version.