# Edit Values of Shapes in List C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, winforms, graphics

Original Question: [Edit properties of Graphics object c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70564205/edit-properties-of-graphics-object-c-sharp/70584297#70584297)

I've managed to create the object models and converted the entire program to use this structure so many thanks for the template there. My only problem is, I need to use threading to implement the color-changing feature. I have implemented the following code but have no luck:

```
       private void pictureBox6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    running = !running;
}

public void redgreenMethod()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (running != true) continue;
        if (flag == false)
        {
            flag = true;
            Shape x = shapes[methodCounter - 1];
            x.pen = Red;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = false;
            Shape x = shapes[methodCounter];
            x.pen = Green;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);

    }

}
```

Surely the code inside the "if" statement changes the pen for the most recently added shape? I've entered a breakpoint and it shows that the pen does change constantly.. however, I don't see this being implemented on the Canvas?!

Where am I going wrong?!

Comment: Most likely `redgreenMethod()` is running in the main UI thread and the tight loop is preventing the controls from updating themselves. Use a TIMER instead. Set its `Interval` property to 500, and handle the `Tick()` event. You don't need the `while` loop then. Instead of `running` you just toggle the `Enabled` state of the Timer.

Comment: So every 500ms you're either setting the pen of the shape at shapes[methodCounter - 1] to Red or setting the pen of the shape at shapes[methodCounter] to Green.  It's hard to guess what you're trying to achieve here without seeing the code where the shapes are drawn and knowing when/why methodCounter gets changed.

Comment: Also, for code like this to be technically correct, any code that reads or writes data shared across threads should be surrounded by a lock block.

Comment: Multithreading is fraught, and it's weird that your instructor would require you to use threads for a problem that is clearly handled better with timers.

Answer (score 0):

From my previous comment:

> Most likely redgreenMethod() is running in the main UI thread and the
> tight loop is preventing the controls from updating themselves. Use a
> TIMER instead. Set its Interval property to 500, and handle the Tick()
> event. You don't need the while loop then. Instead of running you just
> toggle the Enabled state of the Timer.

Here's what that might look like in code:

```
private void pictureBox6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flag = !flag;
    shapes[methodCounter - 1].pen = flag ? Green : Red;
}
```

You made these comments in an answer to your previous question:

> Once a line has been drawn via the graphics: "g.DrawLine", the
> properties of this line are then inaccessible. I need to find out how
> to actually access these properties so I can use them inside the
> Thread method.

In short, you DON'T access the properties of the line that has already been drawn. What you would do is update the color in the Shape (which you're already doing), and then call `Invalidate()` against the control that needs to be redrawn, such as `pictureBox6.Invalidate()`. This will force the `Paint()` event to fire again where everything will then be re-drawn, presumably with the new color that was set in the Shape properties.

Comment: The problem is, the assignment is to specifically use Threads and not a Timer, otherwise, I'd be straight onto using a Timer :(

Comment: See my edit at the bottom for a big clue.

Comment: Absolute legend. Got the alternating colors working! Much appreciated for the help :) The Invalidate fixed it